Loop through map keys in one line in bash
In python, I can do this in one line:
>>> for key, value in dict(j=1, k=2).items():
...     print(key, value)
...
j 1
k 2
>>>

In bash, I can do this:
$ map=([j]=1 [k]=2); for key in ${!map[@]}; do value=${map[$key]}; echo $key $value; done
j 1
k 2
$

Is there a way in bash to "inline" map declaration into for - similarly how it's possible in the python example - instead of declaring it beforehand?
The reason I'm looking for this is to avoid having to declare two additional variables map and value separately - in other words, to make this shorter if possible when doing one-liners on the command line.

To be clear, the general answer is "no" if you're just asking about available syntax; but if you had a practical problem that this syntax would let you solve, describing that problem might allow an answer with an alternate approach.

(...for example, one can certainly write a function that will define an associative array with keys and values from its command line and then call an arbitrary function with each key and value as arguments in turn; so one could write a helper that would meet the letter of your request, but I'm not sure it would be of any practical value to do so absent a use case).

It might help to explain your end goal and where your data comes from (file? command line arguments? What does the format look like?). There's no direct translation for this python feature in bash, but for example if your goal is just to loop over pairs of values there are tools for that depending on how your data is stored.

@CharlesDuffy I don't necessarily have a problem with the above, I'm just looking for a shorter version basically - i.e. avoid having to declare two extra variables (map and value)

@tjm3772 Answered in the previous comment, but let me add to the question as well

You're missing the declare -A map associative array declaration in the question. As it reads now, map=([j]=1 [k]=2) will create a numerically-indexed array with one entry, the value 2 at index 0.

In general, I'd argue that prioritizing terseness in bash is itself an error. The legacy of decades of backwards compatibility requiring extensions and corrections to be in previously-undefined space means that one needs to be very cautious and explicit; terse code is often subtly (or not-so-subtly) buggy code (as glenn demonstrates above).

@glennjackman Ah, must be a remnant of my previous testing where I did declare -A map and it was in the session when I posted the question. Oh well...

You may be missing a better way to do whatever it is you need to do, call it "Y", by approaching it as "if idiom X is how I approach requirement Y in python, then how do I implement X in bash" rather then "how do I approach requirement Y in bash".

In Python, dict(j=1, k=2) is an expression that evaluates to a particular object. In bash, ([j]=1, [k]=2) is not an expression, but an extension of the assignment syntax that allows you to define the value of map without having to write map[j]=1,map[k]=2. bash does not have array values at all, only special syntax for making more-or-less distinct parameters look like a single array.

@EdMorton My last sentence basically. I have a command that needs a key-value pair. I have a list of key-value pairs. I need to run that command for each key-value pair from that list. Python way is natural to me. I'm looking to replicate in bash. It should be short / easy to type / easy to remember. It should read naturally left to right. It should be inlined. for kv in kvs is better than kvs=...; for k in kvs; v=kvs[k] or while read k v; ...; done <<<kvs. Not all will be possible in bash and some are subjective, but the closer, the better.

OK, then this is an "I want my apple to taste like my orange" kind of question and you're just out of luck unless you write your own function to provide the syntax you want.

There's no way around doing
declare -A map=([j]=1 [k]=2)

The "${!map[@]}" parameter expansion requires a declared parameter.

Actually, not true. The parameter expansion happily expands an unset variable into the empty string.


You can drop the value variable
for key in "${!map[@]}"; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$key" "${map[$key]}"
done

Note that associative arrays are unordered. My output for that loop is
k 2
j 1


If you are just looking for a quick way to inspect the contents of a variable, use declare -p
declare -A map=([j]=1 [k]=2)
declare -p map

outputs
declare -A map=([k]="2" [j]="1" )



Is there a way in bash to "inline" map declaration into for - similarly how it's possible in the python example - instead of declaring it beforehand?

No.
You could read two words line by line, but there's no map.
printf "%s %s\n" j 1 k 2 | while read -r key value; do echo "$key" "$value"; done

Check your scripts with shellcheck.

To avoid running the while loop in a subshell, redirect input into it: while read ...; done <<< $'j 1\nk 2'

If you already have an associative array in Bash 5.2+, you can use the @k parameter that expands by alternating keys and values to separate words (see 5.2.t in the changelog), and have printf consume two items at a time:
declare -A map=([j]=1 [k]=2)
printf '%s %s\n' "${map[@]@k}"

Notes:

while keys and values come paired, the sequence of the pairs is unordered (unlike with indexed arrays)
don't confuse @k with @K which was added in 5.1 (see 5.1.hh) and only expands into a single word

But if you only created the array to iterate over its key-value pairs, just provide both keys and values directly to printf:
printf '%s %s\n' j 1 k 2

